# "com.apple.hiservices-xpcservice (Not Responding)" - What is it and how to stop it?

Tags: macos, mojave

In my activity app I can see the an entity in red:

[image]

The process name says "com.apple.hiservices-xpcservice (Not Responding)"

What is this service? What is the impact if I kill it? How can I stop it from reappearing? There were some discussions on apple community forums but I cannot find the answers to my questions.